# firmware failed to load mt7601u.bin in parrotsec

Tags: wifi, parrotsec

So I'm using parrotsec as a VM on UTM, and my real device is a macbook m2.
I want to use my mt7601u wifi adapter apart from the ethernet network I have, but when I connect my wifi adapter to the UTM VM, and run `ifconfig`, wlan0 does not appear.

To solve this problem, I have tried the command `sudo dmesg | grep mt76`, and the following lines appear:

```
[   13.160883] mt7601u 3-3:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[   13.165717] mt7601u 3-3:1.0: firmware: failed to load mt7601u.bin (-2)
[   13.166244] mt7601u 3-3:1.0: firmware: failed to load mt7601u.bin (-2)
[   13.166421] mt7601u 3-3:1.0: Direct firmware load for mt7601u.bin failed with error -2
[   13.168448] mt7601u: probe of 3-3:1.0 failed with error -2
[   13.168490] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
[  533.185957] mt7601u 3-3:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[  533.190371] mt7601u 3-3:1.0: firmware: failed to load mt7601u.bin (-2)
[  533.190599] mt7601u 3-3:1.0: firmware: failed to load mt7601u.bin (-2)
[  533.190766] mt7601u 3-3:1.0: Direct firmware load for mt7601u.bin failed with error -2
[  533.192486] mt7601u: probe of 3-3:1.0 failed with error -2
```

I even tried to rebuild the mt7601u driver using this link https://github.com/terence-deng/mt7601u but to no avail.
What should I do?
Thanks in advance!